# Calendar Planning 2019 - Adding Outlook Appointments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Admin looking for a way to add Outlook appointments/meetings to multiple recipient calendars (33) without cluttering email inbox. Is there a way this can be done directly via the Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, there is not a similar cmdlet or feature to realize this, you need to use EWS Managed API to create appointments and meetings.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-create-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange-2013